# Cannot open 16 files in C program (core dump)

Tags: c, coredump

I created a file pointer array and I get core dump. If I write everything into one file, then my program works fine. What is the reason for this?

This works.

```
unsigned char error_array[4][4][256]
FILE *hypo_table;
hypo_table = fopen("00.txt", "w");
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        for(hypo_key = 0; hypo_key < 256; hypo_key++) {
            //process error_array
            fprintf(hypo_table, "%.2x ", error_array[i][j][hypo_key]);
            if(hypo_key == 255)
                break;
```

This does not work (core dump).

```
unsigned char error_array[4][4][256]
FILE *hypo_table[4][4];
hypo_table[0][0] = fopen("00.txt", "w");
hypo_table[1][0] = fopen("10.txt", "w");
hypo_table[2][0] = fopen("20.txt", "w");
hypo_table[3][0] = fopen("30.txt", "w");

hypo_table[1][0] = fopen("10.txt", "w");
hypo_table[1][1] = fopen("11.txt", "w");
hypo_table[1][2] = fopen("12.txt", "w");
hypo_table[1][3] = fopen("13.txt", "w");

hypo_table[2][0] = fopen("20.txt", "w");
hypo_table[2][1] = fopen("21.txt", "w");
hypo_table[2][2] = fopen("22.txt", "w");
hypo_table[2][3] = fopen("23.txt", "w");

hypo_table[3][0] = fopen("30.txt", "w");
hypo_table[3][1] = fopen("31.txt", "w");
hypo_table[3][2] = fopen("32.txt", "w");
hypo_table[3][3] = fopen("33.txt", "w");


for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        for(hypo_key = 0; hypo_key < 256; hypo_key++) {
            //process error_array
            fprintf(hypo_table[i][j], "%.2x ", error_array[i][j][hypo_key]);
            if(hypo_key == 255)
                break;
```

Comment: On which line does it fail?

Comment: When i = 0, j = 0, hypo_key = 255

Comment: So what about `error_array[i][j][hypo_key]`?

Comment: the loop breaks at 255 because I added a condition.

Comment: @paulsm4, that is a char array.

Comment: Not that this has anything to do with it, but why are you opening 10, 20 and 30 twice? Moreover, are you certain you can do this while requesting **write** access for those files every time? Check the return value of each fopen call and determine whether the file open actually succeeded. You may get EPERM (permission denied). Use perror upon failure to see the error message.

Comment: You are totally correct. The problem is gone now. Thank you. So why the assertion did not fail after I follow the instruction from @EvilTeach. I can take your answer if you post it.

Comment: Side: As files are for text, consider opening files with `"wt"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake you are doing is you are using  uninitialized streams in loop. you are opening same files twice.But you did not opened some files and you did not assign some streams

```
hypo_table[0][0] = fopen("00.txt", "w");
```

Here You did Not opened files  `01.txt`,`02.txt`, and `03.txt`  And
`hypo_table[0][1],hypo_table[0][2],hypo_table[0][3]` are not valid streams

```
hypo_table[1][0] = fopen("10.txt", "w"); //Here ,it is 01 
hypo_table[2][0] = fopen("20.txt", "w"); //Here ,it is 02 
hypo_table[3][0] = fopen("30.txt", "w"); //Here ,it is 03

hypo_table[1][0] = fopen("10.txt", "w"); //Here You are reopening
hypo_table[1][1] = fopen("11.txt", "w");
hypo_table[1][2] = fopen("12.txt", "w");
hypo_table[1][3] = fopen("13.txt", "w");

for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        for(hypo_key = 0; hypo_key < 256; hypo_key++) {
            //process error_array
```

Here you are trying to access invalid streams. this will give segfault.

```
            fprintf(hypo_table[i][j], "%.2x ", error_array[i][j][hypo_key]);
```

---

Use loop to open files and assign streams And check return value of `fopen()` based on return value proceed further.

Use `sprintf()` to create filename strings.

```
FILE *hypo_table[4][4],*fp=NULL;
char buf[10];

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
               sprintf(buf,"%d%d.txt",i,j);    
               fp = fopen(buf, "w");
               if(fp!=NULL)
                  {
                  hypo_table[i][j] =fp;
                  //You can include inner loop Here
                  fp=NULL;  
                  }    
               else
                  {
                  perror("ERROR");
                  //Handle As you want or simply exit. 
                  } 
               }
          }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should recognize the fact that fopen can fail.  There can be an upper limit on the number of files a process can open.

If fopen fails it returns NULL.

If it returns NULL, fprintf will access violated

```
hypo_table[3][3] = fopen("33.txt", "w");  assert(hypo_table[3][3] != NULL);
```

If you toss asserts in there for each one of them, you will see which one is failing.
You will need to #include   to be able to use the assert function.

Normally when you open a file, you should follow something along the line of this pattern:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("some_file.txt", "rw");
if (fp != NULL)
{
    /* Do file stuff */

    fclose(fp);
}
else
{
    printf("golly gee wilkers, the file didn't open\n");
    /* and maybe look at the errno variable to figure out why */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. hypo_key is a unsigned char, the break condition is to prevent infinite loop. I will try assertion now.

Comment: @dannycrane It didn't fail for one of two reasons. The first possibility is that it was opened as if "rw" was just "r" because "rw" only opens on Windows in read-write mode AFAIK; any file writing functions would fail. The other possibility is that it opened in read-write mode as the code indicates, with the default mode being read mode until a file write occurs. This means the file could successfully be opened many times...for reading. Writing is another story. I'm not certain what would happen if one file write occurred using one `FILE *` then another one tried to write.

Answer (score 0):

1) There's no reason you shouldn't be able to open 16 files concurrently.

2) Your 2-D array `hypo_table` looks OK.

3) We don't know anything about your 3-Day array `error_array`.  I suspect that's where your problem is.

4) You should definitely check for all possible error conditions - like "fopen()" failing.

5) You should definitely step through the code under a debugger - this will help you determine exactly *where* it's failing, and *why*.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I added some more details.